# How SEO friendly is this URL?

Tags: asp.net, seo

I have this products catalog site.For the sake of SEO, I would have wanted my 'view details' link to look some thing like this

```
~/products/26-productname or ~/products/26/productname
```

On my machine I'm using a url re-writing module and it works well. Unfortunately My host(shared) does not support url re-writing modules or Aspnet 4.0 for now. So I came up with a workaround that attempts to be SEO friendly

Instead of this :

```
~/Products/details.aspx?id=26
```

I decided to simply append the product name in the url and i.e

```
~/Products/details.aspx?product=26-Toshiba Qosmio Notebook
```

So my question is how SEO friendly is such a URL and is my attempt worth anything at all?

Comment: Either rewrite your app using asp.net MVC or get a new host.

Comment: This is not really programming related.

Comment: Changing hosts is not possible currently. Thats why I was looking for an alternative using the few options I had.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO which is off-topic at Stack Overflow. Please read "[Which SEO questions should be closed as non-programming/non-admin?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382618)" to better understand when SEO questions are acceptable to ask here (most are not). General SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't really make a difference to search engines if you use just a number or a number and a string, but you should make sure that the parameter is recognized correctly:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/10/new-parameter-handling-tool-helps-with.html

Comment: Thanks. I have a better understanding now.

Answer (score 1):

IMO - your URL should read as:

/products/toshiba-qosmio-notebook/

or

/products/26/

and in both cases should point to the same resource. This is more SEO than the link you provided with the query parameters as it points to a resource URI rather than a URL as in your code.

If  your host does not support url-rewrite, perhaps it is time to move to a different host who supports this...

HTH

Comment: Ideally that is what I would have wanted but kind of locked to my host for the next couple of months.

Comment: The trouble is when you postback a page, IIS needs a URL, so I think if you cannot do URL-rewrite, you will need to go to the details.aspx?product= route. In my last project since we had a very small list of products, we were able to create a sub-folder per product & set in IIS that each folders default page as "default.aspx" so when the user could browse by URI, but POSTed to the uri/default.aspx and at the end of the POST processing we would redirect him to the URI. But, our product list was just 3 & never expected to change & so was somewhat manageable.

Answer (score 1):

It is always a good practice to use url which are easily understandable for crawlers. Using certain keywords is also beneficial. http://www.curiologix.com/company-overview.php is an example how your url should be

Answer (score 0):

It is always advisable to use static url, don't go for lengthy statement in url, try adding keywords in url for website promotion.

Answer (score 0):

As far you are using Product URL then according to Google URL Should be understand by the Human.
You can easily get the idea about it by the help of this Google Guide.

http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//webmasters/docs/search-engine-optimization-starter-guide.pdf

So instead of Using this URL

```
~/Products/details.aspx?product=26-Toshiba Qosmio Notebook
```

You should try to resolve it with this type of URL you can remove the Product Id and used something like this.

```
 ~/Products/details/toshiba-qosmio-notebook.aspx
```

It would be Good for your website.

Answer (score 0):

There are various permalink for url but the best url structure for seo is site.com/posturl. you should not repeat the keyword if it is present in root domain. This website has feed all its imp keyword in its url and ranking very well. [https://eloginmentor.online/myhtspace-employee-login-myhtspace-com][1]